# API Key not Found for google maps sdk for android

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view-static-api

I've been struggling w this project for weeks now. Specifically getting the API Keys to work, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code is as follows:

```
package com.example.hopefullyfinalgeoguessr;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.hopefullyfinalgeoguessr.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {

    private StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama;
    private boolean secondlocation = false;
    private static final double MIN_LATITUDE = -90;
    private static final double MAX_LATITUDE = 90;
    private static final double MIN_LONGITUDE = -180;
    private static final double MAX_LONGITUDE = 180;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment = (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemapstreetview);
        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {

        Random random = new Random();
        double lat = MIN_LATITUDE + (MAX_LATITUDE - MIN_LATITUDE) * random.nextDouble();
        double lng = MIN_LONGITUDE + (MAX_LONGITUDE - MIN_LONGITUDE) * random.nextDouble();
        LatLng randomLocation = new LatLng(lat,lng);

        this.streetViewPanorama.setPosition(randomLocation);

    }
}
```

manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Hopefullyfinalgeoguessr"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Hopefullyfinalgeoguessr.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.API_KEY"
                android:value="redacted" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="redacted" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.streetview.API_KEY"
                android:value="redacted" />


        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

layout xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/googlemapstreetview"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried GPT to walk me through this and several YouTube tutorials. I was expecting my street view to load onto the emulator however this is the error message I'm receiving in my logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the      <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

I think that it's due to my project not recognzing the API.

Comment: oh my but error says it all for you? "is in the      <application> element of AndroidManifest.x"

Comment: you forgot to add meta tag for google API key. error showing clearly. So add `<meta-data     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>` in manifest inside application tag

Comment: I did add the meta data tag though? It's clearly in the manifest xml file